# Javascript alert on 3 buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to java script. And I have 3 buttons.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" id="alert">Alert!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-1" id="confirm">Confirm!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info m-1" id="prompt">Prompt!</button>
```

And I need to make an alert popup when clicking on them so for the first one "alert" it will be hello. And for the second it will be an confirm if you are sure or not to continue. The last one is a prompt and just an random name in it.

Thanks for all the answers! :D

Comment: There are many ways to add event handlers. You can use `onclick` in the HTML, you can use `addEventListener()` in Javascript, you can use `.on()` in Javascript with jQuery.

Comment: If you use Google, you will find multiple examples of how this basic task can be achieved.

Comment: Any tutorial on writing Javascript web applications should explain the basics.

Comment: you can visit tizag.com or tutorialspoint.com for learning the basics of JavaScript

Comment: Always try to google and try yourself first, and then ask here with your issue. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('alert').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Hello World');
});
document.getElementById('confirm').addEventListener('click', function() {
  confirm('Are you sure?');
});
document.getElementById('prompt').addEventListener('click', function() {
  prompt('Enter your name');
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" id="alert">Alert!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-1" id="confirm">Confirm!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info m-1" id="prompt">Prompt!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function myFunctionAlert() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}
function myFunctionConfirm() {
    confirm("Are you Sure?");
}
function myFunctionPrompt() {
    prompt("Enter the number");
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" id="alert" onclick="myFunctionAlert()" >Alert!</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-1" id="confirm" onclick="myFunctionConfirm()" >Confirm!</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info m-1" id="prompt" onclick="myFunctionPrompt()" >Prompt!</button>
```

Comment: All 3 functions return allerts.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` as an attribute of your buttons is one possibility:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" id="alert" onclick="alert('Hello');">Alert!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-1" id="confirm" onclick="confirm('Are you sure?');">Confirm!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info m-1" id="prompt" onclick="prompt('Enter something:');">Prompt!</button>
```

---

Or assign an `eventListener` to each of your elements:

```js
document.getElementById('alertButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Hello');
});
document.getElementById('confirmButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  confirm('Are you sure?');
});
document.getElementById('promptButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  prompt('Enter something');
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" id="alertButton">Alert!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-1" id="confirmButton">Confirm!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info m-1" id="promptButton">Prompt!</button>
```

Or use the `onclick` attribute to fire a function:

```js
function someAlert() {
  alert("Hello");
}
function someConfirm() {
  confirm("Are you sure?");
}
function somePrompt() {
  prompt("Enter something:");
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" id="alert" onclick="someAlert()">Alert!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-1" id="confirm" onclick="someConfirm()">Confirm!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info m-1" id="prompt" onclick="somePrompt()">Prompt!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

got it working thanks for your helo

```js
document.getElementById('alertButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Hello');
});
document.getElementById('confirmButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  confirm('Are you sure?');
});
document.getElementById('promptButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  prompt('Enter something');
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" id="alertButton">Alert!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success m-1" id="confirmButton">Confirm!</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info m-1" id="promptButton">Prompt!</button>
```